# Инициализация фигурными скобками допускает сужающие преобразования

Tags: c++, инициализация, language-lawyer, преобразование-типов

```
int main() {
   constexpr auto x = -4294967169u;
   char y{x};
   return y;
}
```

Почему эта программа [компилируется](https://godbolt.org/z/8446KM3hK), хотя инициализация с помощью `{}` не должна допускать narrowing conversions?

Comment: Наверное, потому что `-4294967169u` - это `127`, которое вполне помещается в `char`.

Comment: @EOF но int > char, значит преобразование сужающее

Comment: Но значение константное, значит вычислаяется во время компиляции и компилятор видит, что хоть это и `int`, но значение всё равно помещается в `char`. Вы ведь можете написать `char y{65};`, хоть и  `65` - это `int`.

Comment: Не все что компилируется, соответствует стандарту. Это нормальная ситуация. Плохо, когда то что соответствует стандарту не компилируется.

Comment: @Chorkov то есть это баг компилятора?

Comment: Нет, сужающее преобразование - это когда значение инициализатора не может быть представлено в целевом типе.

Comment: @user7860670 42 может быть представлено в `char`, но пишет, что narrowing conversion компилятор https://godbolt.org/z/raEe7eG1r

Comment: Это совершенно другой пример, в нем значение инициализатора не является константой времени компиляции, соответственно сужающее преобразование при инициализации неизбежно.

Comment: https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1449.html не отмечено как реализованное ни в GCC, ни в Clang

Comment: Так. Предыдущий коммент — лажа.

Answer (score 3):

В строке `char y{x};` из-за наличия фигурных скобок выполняется т.н. *list-initialization*.

[[dcl.init]/16.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.init#general-16.1):

> The semantics of initializers are as follows. ...
>
> - **If the initializer is a** (non-parenthesized) ***braced-init-list*** or is *= braced-init-list*, **the object** or reference **is list-initialized**
>   ([[dcl.init.list]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.init.list)).
> - ...

Действительно, этот тип инициализации не допускает сужающих преобразований.

[[dcl.init.list]/3.9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.init.list#3.9):

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as
> follows:
>
> - ...
> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element of type E and either T is not a reference type or its referenced type is
>   reference-related to E, the object or reference is initialized from
>   that element (by copy-initialization for copy-list-initialization, or
>   by direct-initialization for direct-list-initialization); **if a
>   narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert the element to
>   T, the program is ill-formed**.
> - ...

Однако преобразование в вопросе не является сужающим, т.к. в определении сужающего преобразования сделано исключение для преобразований из константных выражений, если значение помещается в целевой тип.

[[dcl.init.list]/7.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.init.list#7.4):

> A *narrowing conversion* is an implicit conversion
>
> - ...
> - from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, **except
>   where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral
>   promotions will fit into the target type**, or
> - ...

Переменная `x` [может быть использована в константном выражении](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.const#4) и, в [вашей реализации](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:13,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:13,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:13,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:13,startLineNumber:4),source:%27%23include+%3Cclimits%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A+++static_assert(std::is_same_v%3Cdecltype(-4294967169u),+unsigned+int%3E)%3B%0A+++static_assert(sizeof(unsigned+int)+*+CHAR_BIT+%3D%3D+32)%3B%0A+++static_assert(-4294967169u+%3D%3D+127)%3B%0A+++static_assert(CHAR_BIT+%3D%3D+8+%26%26+CHAR_MAX+%3D%3D+127)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:vcpp_v19_29_VS16_11_x64,options:%27/std:c%2B%2B20%27)),editorid:1,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+Viewer+(Editor+%231)+1/15%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), содержит значение `127`,  которое помещается в целевом типе `char` (т.к. 2<sup>32</sup> - 4294967169 = 127 ≤ 2<sup>7</sup> - 1).

[[expr.unary.op]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.unary.op#8):

> ... The negative of an unsigned quantity is computed by subtracting
> its value from 2<sup>n</sup>, where n is the number of bits in the
> promoted operand. ...

```cpp
#include <climits>
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
   static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(-4294967169u), unsigned int>);
   static_assert(sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT == 32);
   static_assert(-4294967169u == 127);
   static_assert(CHAR_BIT == 8 && CHAR_MAX == 127);
}
```

---

Замечу, что теоретически может существовать реализация с `sizeof(-4294967169u) == 8`. В таком случае преобразование будет сужающим.